# Why is the element stale in this case?

Tags: python, selenium

The code looks like:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpathItem10)))

    elementItem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem1)
    elementItem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem2)
    elementItem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem3)
    elementItem4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem4)
    elementItem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem5)
    elementItem6 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem6)
    elementItem7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem7)
    elementItem8 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem8)
    elementItem9 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem9)
    elementItem10 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem10)

    list = [elementItem1, elementItem2, elementItem3, elementItem4, elementItem5, elementItem6, elementItem7, elementItem8, elementItem9, elementItem10]

    patternForFindingListItem = r"some pattern"

    for element in list: # hitta anteckning och klicka på den
        match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)
        print(match)
        if match:
            print(element.text)
            element.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed to load elementItem")


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpathWeek)))

    elementWeek = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathWeek)
    print("Aktuell vecka: " + elementWeek.text)

except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed to load elementWeek")
```

The script navigates successfully to the another page but then this error occurs.

The output:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <div class="widget-care-events__list-item-cell widget-care-events__list-item-cell--type"> is stale; either the eleme
nt is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed
```

The code part after `click()` has nothing to do with the error `xpath` (?). `elementWeek = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathWeek)` has nothing to do with the `xpath` refenced in the error? Not sure why it refences to something on the previous page? I can't get the element back of referenced error with `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath of referenced error)` since the element is not in the new page (only on the page before the element was clicked).

The stacktrace is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tobia\Google-Drive\joint-test.py", line 73, in <module>
    match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)

  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 76, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\tobia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

It shows the problem occurs here (?):

```
match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)
```

Which is on the same site the error occurs on.

After getting a great answer the code now looks like:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpathItem10)))


    list = [xpathItem1, xpathItem2, xpathItem3, xpathItem4, xpathItem5, xpathItem6, xpathItem7, xpathItem8, xpathItem9, xpathItem10]

    patternForFindingListItem = r"some pattern"

    for xpath in list: # hitta anteckning och klicka på den
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) # element fresh each time! no staleness here :-)
        match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)
        print(match)
        if match:
            print(element.text)
            element.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed to load elementItem")
```

The output is `Failed to load elementItem`. Why does this trigger? The code after works but why is the exception triggered?

Edit: I added `break` after the `element.click()` . That made it work without the exception error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click a link and your page changes every previously identified element is now "stale". Consider that Selenium does not your store your identifier - it store "the object" that it found. A different page would a different object even if it's identified the same.

Explaining this with your code....

When you do this:

```
    elementItem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem1)
    elementItem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem2)
    elementItem3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem3)
    etc...
```

You're identifying and storing the selenium web elements. Selenium now stores the element references (not your identifiers).

When you do this:

```
  for element in list: # hitta anteckning och klicka på den
        match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)
        print(match)
        if match:
            print(element.text)
            element.click()
```

Key lines and logic:

- First time in the loop `element.text` works because elements are valid
- End of the loop `element.click()` - You're navigating to a new page.
- Start of the next iteration `element.text` - it wants the next element in your list - that is now stale. It's a new page.

One solution is to loop through xpaths (not elements) and use driver to identify the element within the loop.

First step - Get rid of this bit entirely:

```
    elementItem1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem1)
    elementItem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathItem2)
    ...etc..
```

Second - Change your list creation collection step to be **a list of xpath strings**:

```
 list = [xpathItem1, xpathItem2, xpathItem3, ...etc...]
```

Finally, update your loop to use driver and find the fresh element each time:

```
    for xpath in list: # hitta anteckning och klicka på den
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) # element fresh each time! no staleness here :-)
        match = re.search(patternForFindingListItem, element.text)
        print(match)
        if match:
            print(element.text)
            element.click()
```

You haven't shared your url so can't test this for you. The code has been statically typed in here. If you have any continued problems please say and I will be happy to support.

You might also need to consider adding a wait condition in the loop on the identify - and a see you have a webdriverwait earlier in your code so I'm assuming you understand how to use it.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your clear explanations and your code. It certainly helped me! Now I am getting the the following custom error; `Failed to load elementItem.` But the code runs and it works except the custom error. WHen processing the code it waits a little bit  before ouputting the custom error. Any idea why the `except TimeoutException:` triggers?

Comment: I added `break` after the `element.click()` . That made it work without the exception error.